# Words that are similar to or means 'yes' and 'no'

Tags: nlp, synonym

I'm wondering if there's a corpus for words that basically means "yes" or "no"? If not, what are the possible algorithms/techniques to collect such information?

I just started to learn NLP, so please bear with me if this is an obvious question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to find the similar words in a certain corpus of words.

In order to measure words similarity you can use a model called [Word2Vec](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf) that was introduced by Mikolov et al.

If you train this model on a corpus of words it maps each word to it's representation in a vector space. Basically each word will be represented by a vector (where the nome Word2Vec). Word2vec assigns high similarity to words that tend to appear in the same context.

After that you can measure words similarity by calculating the cosine similarity of these two word vectors.

Here are the results that I get when training Word2vec in a corpus of product reviews:

- First 4 most similar words to yes:
- 'yeah', 'oh', 'hey', 'sure'
- First 4 most similar words to no:
- 'whatsoever', discernible', 'denying', zero

Some Word2vec references :

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

http://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/

EDIT:
You can find related words to No and Yes in the general inquirer website as well

http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/No.html

http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/Yes.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for providing a thorough answer! I guess it's important to look for the corpus with a lot of examples of "yes", "yeah", "yeh" and so on then.